# Do students get rejected if they did bad on a graduate interview despite having a strong cv?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, graduate-school, cv, interview

Long story short, I did bad in a graduate interview because I was not prepared and I am in a depressive episode but was trying to fight it, I am way better than what I presented myself as, I felt that the committee found it weird because my cgpa is very high, the referees wrote me very strong recommendation letters and my BSc. thesis is very good and I presented a poster in a prestigious conference.

1. Does this mean that I will get rejected for sure?
2. As a professor doing an interview, how would you judge such a student?
3. If I got rejected and applied again for the next year. Will I be considered?

Comment: One thing to consider is that depression systematically distorts your (self-)perceptions. So, unless you received some objectively negative feedback, it's not unlikely that you did much better than you think.

Comment: Answer to all three questions: no one knows. I sympathize with your situation, but the honest truth is your question is unanswerable. Take care, and I hope things work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you get rejected *for sure*, but it is possible.

If I felt the interview was wildly inconsistent with the written record I'd either make my best judgement call or possibly suggest another interview. But the latter only if the written record is really outstanding. And as lighthouse keeper mentioned, your judgement may, itself be clouded at the moment.

I doubt that there would be any carryover.

Your other information suggests that your record is good enough that you will probably be fine - unless you called the interviewer a "witch", of course.

And if depression is an issue for you, then you need to get some professional advice to help you deal with it. Graduate study is hard enough in the best case.

Answer (score 1):

Depends in part on how the other candidates fared.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that people who are confident think they did well and people who are nervous think they did poorly. Whereas i think nervous is fine if you can talk about stuff and very confident people are often very confidently wrong and come off like morons. So I'm not sure if your gut feeling is a good judge of how well you did.

That said, one really bad interview might be enough to tank you. A middling interview is fine if the rest of your application is ok, but if you've convinced someone you're not capable of the work you'll have to do, they'll prevail when it comes to not accepting you.